# Keycloak : Redirection loop using javascript adapter behind nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a Javascript client authenticating using OIDC against keycloak.

The authentication works fine in development environment but end in a redirection loop when using a reverse proxy between the client and the backend (including keycloak)

Looks like the authentication succeed (the `/token` request end with http 200 and the response include all the tokens) but then the `login-status-iframe.html`  does not detect it as successful and restart an authentication flow again and again

What is the problem here (nginx configuration ?)

Comment: This could potentially be a cross-domain issue introduced by the reverse proxy, you may want to look into the `X-Frame-Options` header or ensure the iframe is served from the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got a solution.
The issue came from our cookies set as HttpOnly : this seems to prevent the iframe to access session data and force the iframe to re-authenticate, hence causing the infinite loop.

The deactivation of HttpOnly flag *on this cookie only* solved the problem.

Comment: how & where exactly did you disable the httpOnly cookie header?

Comment: Could you please specify where has this setting to be done?

Comment: @Alexandre-combe can you explain where did you make this change. We are having similar problem.